# Trait implementation for both a trait object and for direct implementors of the trait

Tags: rust, traits

I have a struct that mostly encapsulates a vector:

```
struct Group<S> {
    elements: Vec<S>
}
```

I also have a simple trait which is also implemented for other structs:

```
trait Solid {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32;
}
```

I want to implement `Solid` for `Group`, but I want to be able to use `Group` both for lists of the same implementation of `Solid` and for lists of mixed implementations of `Solid`. Basically I want to use both `Group<Box<Solid>>` and `Group<Sphere>` (`Sphere` implements `Solid`).

Currently I am using something like this:

```
impl Solid for Group<Box<dyn Solid>> {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32 {
        //do stuff
    }
}

impl<S: Solid> Solid for Group<S> {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32 {
        //do the same stuff, code copy-pasted from previous impl
    }
}
```

This works, but having line-for-line the same code twice can't be the idiomatic solution. I must be missing something obvious?

In my case I measure a notable performance difference between both trait implementations, so always using `Group<Box<Solid>>` isn't a great option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Implement your trait for all `Box<S>` where `S` implements your trait. Then you can delegate to the existing implementation:

```
impl<S: Solid + ?Sized> Solid for Box<S> {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32 {
        (**self).intersect(ray)
        // Some people prefer this less-ambiguous form
        // S::intersect(self, ray)
    }
}
```

You'll also find that it can be useful to do the same for references:

```
impl<S: Solid + ?Sized> Solid for &'_ S {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32 {
        (**self).intersect(ray)
        // Some people prefer this less-ambiguous form
        // S::intersect(self, ray)
    }
}
```

All together:

```
trait Solid {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32;
}

impl<S: Solid + ?Sized> Solid for Box<S> {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32 {
        (**self).intersect(ray)
        // S::intersect(self, ray)
    }
}

impl<S: Solid + ?Sized> Solid for &'_ S {
    fn intersect(&self, ray: f32) -> f32 {
        (**self).intersect(ray)
        // S::intersect(self, ray)
    }
}

struct Group<S>(Vec<S>);

impl<S: Solid> Solid for Group<S> {
    fn intersect(&self, _ray: f32) -> f32 {
        42.42
    }
}

struct Point;

impl Solid for Point {
    fn intersect(&self, _ray: f32) -> f32 {
        100.
    }
}

fn main() {
    let direct = Group(vec![Point]);
    let boxed = Group(vec![Box::new(Point)]);
    let pt = Point;
    let reference = Group(vec![&pt]);

    let mixed: Group<Box<dyn Solid>> = Group(vec![
        Box::new(direct),
        Box::new(boxed),
        Box::new(Point),
        Box::new(reference),
    ]);

    mixed.intersect(1.0);
}
```

The `?Sized` bound allows the `S` to not have a size known at compile time. Importantly, this allows you to pass in *trait objects* such as `Box<dyn Solid>` or `&dyn Solid` as the type `Solid` does not have a known size.

See also:

- [What does the question mark mean in a type parameter bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30333607/155423)
- [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/155423)
- [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)

Comment: @CarlLevasseur I've updated the existing sentence about `?Sized`; is it any clearer?

Comment: Yes, so if `Box<Solid>` is a `Solid`, then to use it in a function that takes a `&Solid`, we would have 2 "redirections", does that have an impact on performances ? Also, when is it useful to implement it for references ?

Comment: @CarlLevasseur *does that have an impact on performance* — that depends on a lot of things (frequency of calls, compiler optimizations, monomorphization, etc.). The **only** answer for that is to profile to be sure. *when is it useful to implement it for references* — whenever you have a trait object reference instead of a boxed trait object ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220053/155423))... I don't think I fully understand the question.

Comment: Why is the '(**self).intersect(ray)' part able to compile? I assume that '**self' is '?Sized', which may not necessarily be able to live on stack.

Comment: @GarlicXu it doesn't need to live on the stack though. The compiler will automatically insert a reference when the method call is made: [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423)

Comment: Why is `S::intersect(self, ray)` not resolved as a recursive call? Given that `self` has type `&&S`, and the `impl ... for &'_ S` block's `intersect` method also wants `self: &&S`, why does this method not take priority according to the rules?

Comment: @GarlicXu because `S` is a specific type. Our method is defined on `&S`, so `S::intersect` **must** refer to the dereferenced version.