# How do I get the runtime memory size of an object?

Tags: memory, rust

I am trying to figure out how to get the size in bytes of an object in Rust where the size may or may not be known at compile time. I would like to be able to fetch the number of bytes at any point during the runtime of the program. Here's an example.

```rust
let mut v: Vec<SomeStruct> = Vec::new();

loop {

    v.push(get_some_struct());

    print_consumed_memory_of_vec(&v);
}
```

I would like to have a more generic way this than doing `mem::size_of<SomeStruct> * v.len()` because often you have a trait or something where the size is not known at compile time.

Comment: Nothing has changed for the past couple for years, so this should be an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691288/size-of-a-box-containing-a-struct-with-a-trait-parameter

Answer (score 22):

Use [`std::mem::size_of_val`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html) to get the size of a slice:

```
println!("The useful size of `v` is {}", size_of_val(&*v));
```

Note:

- You must dereference a `Vec<T>` to get a `&[T]` because the size of the `Vec` itself is just the size of three pointers, but you actually want the size of the slice that the data pointer refers to. This isn't a problem when you already have a `&[T]` or a `&dyn Trait`, or generally any `&U` where `U` is the thing whose size you want to know.
- This gives you the size of the *populated* part of the `Vec`; that is, the same thing as `size_of::<T>() * v.len()`. If `v` has unused capacity, that will not be reflected by `size_of_val(&*v)`. There is no general method that tells you the size of an allocation; you must calculate that yourself. This also makes a difference for, for instance, `Rc<T>` instead of `Vec<T>` -- the `Rc` stores its reference counts in the same allocation with the `T`, but they will not be counted if you write `size_of_val(&*rc)`.

Comment: Thanks @trentcl . Your notes were especially helpful. I wasn't dereferencing to get the slice.