# How can I write a builder that stores a Path?

Tags: path, rust, borrowing

The `Path` argument could be immediately converted into a `PathBuf`, but that seems inefficient. There has to be some way of keeping just a `Path`, right?

```rust
use std::{fs::File, path::Path};

struct Foo {
    a: Option<File>,
    b: Option<File>,
}

struct FooBuilder<'a> {
    a: Option<&'a Path>,
    b: Option<&'a Path>,
}

impl<'a> FooBuilder<'a> {
    fn new() -> FooBuilder<'a> {
        FooBuilder { a: None, b: None }
    }

    fn a<P: AsRef<Path> + 'a>(&'a mut self, a: P) -> &mut FooBuilder<'a> {
        self.a = Some(a.as_ref());
        self
    }

    fn b<P: AsRef<Path> + 'a>(&'a mut self, b: P) -> &mut FooBuilder<'a> {
        self.b = Some(b.as_ref());
        self
    }

    fn done(&self) -> Foo {
        Foo {
            a: match self.a {
                Some(path) => Some(File::open(path).unwrap()),
                None => None,
            },
            b: match self.b {
                Some(path) => Some(File::open(path).unwrap()),
                None => None,
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let path1 = Path::new("1");
    let path2 = Path::new("2");
    let _foo = FooBuilder::new().a(path1).b(path2).done();
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:23
   |
13 | impl<'a> FooBuilder<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
19 |         self.a = Some(a.as_ref());
   |         --------------^----------
   |         |             |
   |         |             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         assignment requires that `a` is borrowed for `'a`
20 |         self
21 |     }
   |     - `a` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:24:23
   |
13 | impl<'a> FooBuilder<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
24 |         self.b = Some(b.as_ref());
   |         --------------^----------
   |         |             |
   |         |             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         assignment requires that `b` is borrowed for `'a`
25 |         self
26 |     }
   |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```rust
use std::{fs::File, path::Path};

struct Foo {
    a: Option<File>,
}

struct FooBuilder<'a> {
    a: Option<&'a Path>,
}

impl<'a> FooBuilder<'a> {
    fn new() -> FooBuilder<'a> {
        FooBuilder { a: None }
    }

    fn a<P>(&mut self, a: &'a P) -> &mut FooBuilder<'a>
    where
        P: AsRef<Path> + ?Sized,
    {
        self.a = Some(a.as_ref());
        self
    }

    fn build(&self) -> Foo {
        Foo {
            a: self.a.map(|path| File::open(path).unwrap()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let path1 = Path::new("1");
    let _foo = FooBuilder::new().a(path1).build();
}
```

Let's focus on the `a` method:

```rust
fn a<P>(&mut self, a: &'a P) -> &mut FooBuilder<'a>
where
    P: AsRef<Path> + ?Sized,
```

This method accepts a *reference* to a type that implements `AsRef<Path>`. That means that we can get a reference to a `Path` with the same lifetime as the parameter. The other change is to make the `Sized` bound optional for the type via `?`. This means that we can have a reference to something that we don't know  how big it is. This is fine as we will know how big the *reference itself* is.

Let's compare this to your original version:

```rust
fn a<P: AsRef<Path> + 'a>(&'a mut self, a: P) -> &mut FooBuilder<'a> {
    self.a = Some(a.as_ref());
    self
}
```

Here, the `a` parameter is passed-by-value into the method `a`. When you call `as_ref`, you are implicitly calling it on a *reference* to the item that is on the stack frame of the method call. The referred-to item will be dropped at the end of the method call, which means that the reference would become invalid. That is the reasoning behind the `` error: `a` does not live long enough `` error you were getting.

I also used `Option::map` to clean up the `build` method. I renamed it to `build` because *builders* should generally have a `build` method, unless there's a more obvious verb to use (like `open`).

See also:

- [What does the question mark mean in a type parameter bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30333607/155423)

Comment: this helped me. i'd like to add something that is stated several times in the rust book, as well as implicitly here, but still may slip up folks new to rust: `Sized` is the default and implicit.