# Cannot return Option<associated type> because associated type is not sized

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I don't understand why this code does not compile:

```
fn main() {}

trait NotWorking {
    // The associated type `Bar` must be sized
    type Bar: ?Sized;

    // Why does the compiler complain that Self::Bar is not sized?
    // I have a trait bound that says it is!
    fn notwoking() -> Option<Self::Bar>;
}
```

I do have a constraint that the associated type `Bar` must be sized, but the compiler still complains that it's unsized:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<Self as NotWorking>::Bar: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     fn notwoking() -> Option<Self::Bar>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `<Self as NotWorking>::Bar` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `<Self as NotWorking>::Bar`
   = help: consider adding a `where <Self as NotWorking>::Bar: std::marker::Sized` bound
   = note: required by `std::option::Option`
```

I played a bit with this, trying to make it work, and was surprised that this works (since we can't return a type that is unsized, I was expecting it to fail):

```
fn main() {}

trait Working {
    type Bar;

    // Why does this work?
    // I would expect the compiler to complain the Self::Bar is not sized
    fn woking() -> Self::Bar;
}
```

I'm definitely missing something important here.

Comment: oooh I just noticed that my `NotWorking` example is working when I specify `Sized` instead of `?Sized`.

Comment: `?Sized` means *no need to be sized*: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is correct. The way you declare a generic parameter with a `Sized` bound is by not specifying any explicit bounds. `Sized` is special in that it is implicitly added as a bound on generic parameters by default because it is relatively uncommon for things to not be `Sized`. In cases where you don't want to require a generic parameter to have a size known at compile time, you can [remove this implicit bound by writing `?Sized`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30333607/155423).

See also the [documentation for `Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the last string:

```
required by `std::option::Option`
```

I'm not an expert but I guess the compiler needs information about the type's size to know how to layout the variant typed `Bar` of the enum `Option` in memory.