# "Use of type variable from outer function" in a closure that creates a thread-local variable of that type

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a threadpool where each thread in the pool has a `thread_local!`  type which can be used by tasks on that worker thread.  (`T` in the example below). The key purpose of the class is that the resource `T` need not be `Send`, since it will be constructed locally on each worker thread by a factory method which *is* `Send`.

My use case is to do work on a pool of `!Send` db connections, but I tried to make it generic over the resource type `T`.

```
extern crate threadpool;

use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::sync::Arc;

// A RemoteResource is a threadpool that maintains a threadlocal ?Send resource
// on every pool in the thread, which tasks sent to the pool can reference.
// It can be used e.g., to manage a pool of database connections.
struct RemoteResource<T, M>
where
    M: 'static + Send + Sync + Fn() -> T,
{
    pool: threadpool::ThreadPool,
    make_resource: Arc<M>,
}

impl<T, M> RemoteResource<T, M>
where
    M: Send + Sync + Fn() -> T,
{
    pub fn new(num_workers: usize, make_resource: M) -> Self {
        RemoteResource {
            pool: threadpool::ThreadPool::new(num_workers),
            make_resource: Arc::new(make_resource),
        }
    }

    pub fn call<F, R>(&mut self, f: F) -> R
    where
        R: 'static + Send,
        F: 'static + ::std::marker::Send + FnOnce(&mut T) -> R,
    {
        let (tx, rx) = channel();
        let maker = self.make_resource.clone();
        self.pool.execute(move || {
            use std::cell::RefCell;
            thread_local!{
                static UNSENDABLE_TYPE: RefCell<Option<T>> = RefCell::new(None)
            }
            UNSENDABLE_TYPE.with(|it| {
                let mut mine = it.borrow_mut();
                if mine.is_none() {
                    *mine = Some(maker());
                }
                if let Some(ref mut mine) = *mine {
                    let res = f(mine);
                    tx.send(res).unwrap();
                    return ();
                }
                unreachable!()
            });
        });
        rx.recv().unwrap()
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c84de241dc0fc9f1fd9c007e53b68e9d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Unfortunately I can't get my code to typecheck when I abstract over `T`:

```
error[E0401]: can't use type parameters from outer function
  --> src/lib.rs:38:56
   |
17 | impl<T, M> RemoteResource<T, M>
   |      - type variable from outer function
...
28 |     pub fn call<F, R>(&mut self, f: F) -> R
   |            ---- try adding a local type parameter in this method instead
...
38 |                 static UNSENDABLE_TYPE: RefCell<Option<T>> = RefCell::new(None)
   |                                                        ^ use of type variable from outer function
```

I tried to resolve this using the suggestions in the Rust Compiler Error Index, but "copying the type over" doesn't work. If if "copy" `T` into `call`, then I get a "shadowed type variable" error. If I introduce a new type `U`, then I get a very confusing E401 again, but this time suggesting that I try to add a type parameter to the type parameters on `call`, exactly where I've actually already added it. This second thing looks like a bug in the compiler to me. (If you're curious about that, [here's the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c6b32c3f67fc6bdc20bfb1a1f51058e0&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)).

Is it possible to get this to typecheck? If not, why not?

Comment: `?Send` — it is [not possible to define such a bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333607/what-does-the-question-mark-mean-in-a-type-parameter-bound); you may only say `?Sized`.

Comment: Good to know. I reworded for clarity.

Comment: The error message is bad – see also [this bug report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54560)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the closure and everything to do with `static`. Here's a smaller example that produces the same error:

```
fn foo<T>() {
    static BAR: Option<T> = None;
}
```

A `static` in a generic function will not generate one static for each `T`; there is only one `static` variable. Take the following program, for example:

```
fn foo<T>() {
    static mut COUNTER: i32 = 0;
    unsafe {
        COUNTER += 1;
        println!("{}", COUNTER);
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo::<i32>();
    foo::<u64>();
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
```

Here, `foo::<i32>` and `foo::<u64>` both share the same counter. Considering this, it doesn't make sense to define a single static whose type depends on the type parameter of its enclosing generic function, since that function can be instantiated multiple times.

Unfortunately, there's no way to define a "generic `static`" that is instantiated for each `T` that is used. What you can do instead is define some sort of typemap (i.e. a map from `TypeId` to `Box<Any>`) and perform a dynamic lookup in that map.

Comment: *A static in a generic function will not generate one static for each `T`* — any reason you know of for why? I'm asking around, but I can't figure out any specific reason; it seems like it could be a form of monomorphization.

Comment: When everything is built statically, that could work, but if the application uses dynamically linked libraries, there could be multiple instantiations of the same variable. For example, crate A defines a generic `static` but doesn't instantiate it, then crates B and C both instantiate it for the same type. For functions, this is generally not a problem because we (often) don't care that there are two identical functions.

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic answer! Much appreciated.

Comment: @FrancisGagné won't that happen in the "normal" case as well? Won't two dylibs that each define a `static FOO` (even from the same shared crate) have distinct memory addresses?

Comment: @Shepmaster If you try to build a binary with a mix of static and dynamic libs, you end up with errors like `error: cannot satisfy dependencies so \`std\` only shows up once`, which means that in practice, I don't think you can have two dylibs that contain the same crate (that shared crate must be a dylib too).