# Trait objects, and reading n bytes into vector

Tags: rust, traits

Say I have the following,

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum FooReadError {
    UnexpectedEof,
    IoError(io::Error),
}

impl From<io::Error> for FooReadError {
    fn from(err: io::Error) -> FooReadError {
        FooReadError::IoError(err)
    }
}

fn read_n_bytes_to_vector<R: Read>(reader: &mut R, length: usize)
        -> Result<Vec<u8>, FooReadError> {
    let mut bytes = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(length);
    unsafe { bytes.set_len(length); }
    let bytes_read = try!(reader.read(&mut bytes[..]));
    if bytes_read != length {
        Err(FooReadError::UnexpectedEof)
    } else {
        Ok(bytes)
    }
}

fn do_some_read(reader: &mut Read) -> Vec<u8> {
    read_n_bytes_to_vector(reader, 16).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut cur = io::Cursor::<Vec<u8>>::new(v);
    do_some_read(&mut cur);
}
```

The `read_n_bytes_to_vector` is supposed to take anything implementing the trait `io::Read`, read `length` bytes from it, and put them into a vector and return the vector.

The function `do_some_read` has a `io::Read` trait *object*. So, why then:

```
% rustc ./vec_read.rs
./vec_read.rs:29:5: 29:27 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `std::io::Read` [E0277]
./vec_read.rs:29     read_n_bytes_to_vector(reader, 16).unwrap()
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./vec_read.rs:29:5: 29:27 note: `std::io::Read` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
./vec_read.rs:29     read_n_bytes_to_vector(reader, 16).unwrap()
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I agree with the compiler that `io::Read` can't possibly implement `Sized`; but I'm passing a trait *object* — those are constant-size, so it should be okay here; **so why the error?* But wait, why does it even matter? The function isn't taking an `io::Read` for an arg (*right?*), it's taking a trait object too, because the arg is generic, and should take the full type of what's passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics include the `Sized` bound by default; if you do not wish it to be required, you must add the `?Sized` bound.

A trait object is *not* of constant size; `u16 as Trait` is two bytes, `u32 as Trait` is four bytes, *&c.*; only things like *boxed* trait objects (`Box<Trait>`) and trait object *references* (`&Trait`, `&mut Trait`) have a constant size, known at compile time (two words for the cited examples).

Because you only use an `R` by mutable reference, you can add the `?Sized` bound successfully:

```
fn read_n_bytes_to_vector<R: ?Sized + Read>(reader: &mut R, length: usize)
        -> Result<Vec<u8>, FooReadError> {
```

Comment: Reading [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html), which says, "Trait objects, like `&Foo` or `Box<Foo>`" lead me to believe that they were a constant size (the size of two pointers, one for the object, one for the vtable). The docs there show the `foo_obj as &Trait` coercion, but not `foo_obj as Trait`. What does the latter do differently? Also, aren't I using the `&Foo`, which you say *is* constant size, so why do I need `?Sized`? (Nonetheless, your solution works, but I can't explain why, I guess?)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044231/what-does-sized-is-not-implemented-mean) seems to say similar things. Correct me if I'm wrong (testing if I understand); remembering that `Sized` is part of the generic's bound by default (like you say), `R` in my example matches _only_ `Read` in `&mut Read` (the `&mut` not being part of the bound, but part of _that specific use of R_ in the arg); so `R` is `Read`, but `R` needs to satisfy `Sized + Read`, which `Read` of course isn't. Thus, we need to opt-out with `?Sized`.

Still curious what/if `foo_type as Trait` does, if anything?

Comment: (Ick, that documentation is very sloppy about the term “trait objects”.) Unsized types cannot be instantiated directly; they can only be created through some form of indirection, such as `Box<T>` and `&T`, because the sizes vary. `foo as Trait` thus doesn’t actually compile; I’m using it to express the concept of what is being pointed *to*. It’s a bit of a complex subject, really.