# Why isn't a Box automatically Sized?

Tags: rust, reactor, mio

I am trying to implement a server using Mio and a reactor pattern. I want my `Reactor` to handle both `TcpListeners` and `TcpStreams`, so abstracting over that is my real challenge here.

I have a trait `ReAgent` that implements various handlers for informing the `Reactor` about changes in status, while `Reactor` informs each individual `ReAgent` about events important to that `ReAgent`.  In turn, I'll have two different `ReAgent` types, one for accepting (`TcpListeners`) which will spawn clients (`TcpStreams`) to pass back to the `Reactor` for event handling.  A very standard `Reactor` pattern for multiple server endpoints; I've written half a dozen of these in C/C++ over my career.  Eliding details about my `TokenPool`, etc., here's where my headache lies:

```
pub struct Reactor<'a> {
    poll: Poll,
    agents: HashMap<Token, Box<ReAgent + 'a>>,
    tokens: TokenPool,
}


impl<'a> Reactor<'a> {
    pub fn add_agent<R: ReAgent + 'a>(&mut self, mut agent: Box<R>) -> Result<()>
    {
        if let Some(next_token) = self.tokens.pop() {
            agent.set_token(next_token);
            self.agents.insert(agent.get_token(), agent);
            return Ok(())
        } 
        bail!(ErrorKind::ConnectionsExhausted)
    }
}

//... 

/// Received a Box<ReAgent> (a Client);
/// add and start conversation
Some(boxed_agent) => self.add_agent(boxed_agent)
```

When I compile this, I get:

```
Some(boxed_agent) => self.add_agent(boxed_agent)
                          ^^^^^^^^^ `reagent::ReAgent` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
```

... which I don't get at all.  It's a `Box`.  A `Box` has a known constant size at compile time.  That's the whole point here of using `Box` to support a dynamic type object, right?  The client has a known size, it's a concrete implementation of `ReAgent`.

What am I missing?

I know I'll probably have to use a `RefCell` later, since I'm mutating the `ReAgent` to set its polling token; that's for later, I just want to get past this.

Comment: "C/C++", C or C++ ? XD that make me mad... whatever your MCVE is not complete what is `reagent::ReAgent` ? (I suppose it's a trait and this trait don't have a compile size, AFAIK)

Comment: I think [What does "Sized is not implemented" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044231/what-does-sized-is-not-implemented-mean) might be a closer match.

Comment: Either way, the application is: add `+ ?Sized` to the bounds on `R` and it should work :)

Comment: Addressing your title: `Box` is sized, as you said. That's why the error message says: ***\`reagent::ReAgent\`** does not have a constant size known at compile-time*.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's my point: Box is a pointer object. It has a constant size.  Why does the receiver function care what size the thing pointed to?  None of the recommended answers pointed to give me a clear answer to that question.

Comment: @ElfSternberg the first sentence of the [accepted answer of the first linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28045264/155423) states, emphasis mine: *The `Sized` trait is rather special, so special that **it is a default bound on type parameters** in most situations*. You have a type parameter (`R`). It has the `Sized` type bound. The trait type `ReAgent` does not have a size, thus it fails the requirements.