# Do I have to implement a trait twice when implementing it for both reference and non-reference types?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to implement a trait for both a for reference and non-reference type. Do I have to implement the functions twice, or this is not idiomatic to do so?

Here's the demo code:

```
struct Bar {}

trait Foo {
    fn hi(&self);
}

impl<'a> Foo for &'a Bar {
    fn hi(&self) {
        print!("hi")
    }
}

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn hi(&self) {
        print!("hi")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar {};
    (&bar).hi();
    &bar.hi();
}
```

Comment: code link https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1da24704be6ac37bf02c527e7cb4095a

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a good example for the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait.

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Bar;

trait Foo {
    fn hi(&self);
}

impl<B: Borrow<Bar>> Foo for B {
    fn hi(&self) {
        print!("hi")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar;
    (&bar).hi();
    &bar.hi();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `Into`/`TryInto`/`From`/`TryFrom`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: It looks like this does now work for From, using `impl <BB: Borrow<B>> From<BB> for A`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dee1870b554a39fa011ecf710486d4a7

Comment: @poolie Thanks for pointing this out! Unfortunately I don't think that it works for converting from more than one type into your desired type. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38d71ad7e64931e6bd3a61f1f4d0424c

Answer (score 8):

No, you do not have to duplicate code. Instead, you can delegate:

```
impl Foo for &'_ Bar {
    fn hi(&self) {
        (**self).hi()
    }
}
```

I would go one step further and implement the trait for all references to types that implement the trait:

```
impl<T: Foo> Foo for &'_ T {
    fn hi(&self) {
        (**self).hi()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423)
- [Implementing a trait for reference and non reference types causes conflicting implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48432842/155423)

---

> ```
> &bar.hi();
> ```

This code is equivalent to `&(bar.hi())` and probably not what you intended.

See also:

- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)

Comment: What's the best practice when the trait is external, e.g., when we want to implement the Index trait for a type and its reference type, including the mut variants?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar;

trait Foo {
    fn hi(self) -> &'static str;
}

impl<'a, B> Foo for B where B: Into<Cow<'a, Bar>> {
    fn hi(self) -> &'static str {
        let bar = self.into();

        // bar is either owned or borrowed:
        match bar {
            Cow::Owned(_) => "Owned",
            Cow::Borrowed(_) => "Borrowed",
        }
    }
}

/* Into<Cow> implementation */

impl<'a> From<Bar> for Cow<'a, Bar> {
    fn from(f: Bar) -> Cow<'a, Bar> {
        Cow::Owned(f)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a Bar> for Cow<'a, Bar> {
    fn from(f: &'a Bar) -> Cow<'a, Bar> {
        Cow::Borrowed(f)
    }
}

/* Proof it works: */

fn main() {
    let bar = &Bar;
    assert_eq!(bar.hi(), "Borrowed");

    let bar = Bar;
    assert_eq!(bar.hi(), "Owned");
}
```

The one advantage over `Borrow` is that you know if the data was passed by value or reference, if that matters to you.