# Overloading reference and value calls

Tags: rust, overloading

I've got three functions with signatures like the following (slightly simplified below):

```
fn f<T>(f: impl Fn(&T), x : &impl ATrait<T>) {}
fn f<T>(f: impl Fn(&T), x : impl ATrait<T>) {}
fn f<T>(f: impl Fn(T), x : impl ATrait<T>) {}
```

Naturally as they're all named `f` this won't compile but is there anyway I can give them the same name through traits+impls or other methods so I can do:

```
f(|&e| {}, &x);
f(|&e| {}, x);
f(|e| {}, x);
```

and it selects the correct overload based on argument type?

Comment: if your function can work without consume `x` why would you need more than one version ?!?

Comment: The version which consumes `x` can do things like skip a full copy because we can just mutate `x`.

I've simplified the functions they actually all return (the same value). They're roughly speaking like `Option.map`.

Comment: if you need to consume the value just take by value and let the caller perform copy if needed

Comment: Actually there's no copies in either case it's just one creates a new object and the other modifies in place. 

But that's not always the case it depends on exact type of the second argument as it's a trait so the implementations can be different.

Comment: I don't follow you, by using `impl ATrait`, you can't know the real type, that the point of this syntax. So you can't know what implementation is doing.

Comment: You can learn from my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555910/do-i-have-to-implement-a-trait-twice-when-implementing-it-for-both-reference-and/56609965#56609965