# implement one trait for multiple Borrow<T> types causes conflicting implementations

Tags: rust, traits

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Foo {
    fn bar();
}

struct S {}

impl <B: Borrow<S>> Foo for B {
    fn bar(){
        print!("bar");
    }
}

struct D {}

impl <B: Borrow<D>> Foo for B {
    fn bar(){
        print!("bar")
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Code above causes an compiler error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Foo`:
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
9  |     impl <B: Borrow<S>> Foo for B {
   |     ----------------------------- first implementation here
...
17 |     impl <B: Borrow<D>> Foo for B {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

I asked a question here [Do I have to implement a trait twice when implementing it for both reference and non-reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555910/do-i-have-to-implement-a-trait-twice-when-implementing-it-for-both-reference-and)

The accepted answer works well when there's only one struct that implements this trait.

How can I do if I want to implement trait `Foo` for both `Borrow<S>` and `Borrow<D>`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What if a type implements both `Borrow<S>` and `Borrow<D>`? Your two blanket implementations will be in conflict!

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to use another solution mentioned in the original thread.