# implement trait for owned and borrowed

Tags: generics, rust, traits, ownership, borrowing

I have the following rust snippet:

```rust
trait Foo { 
    fn foo(&self); 
}

struct FooImpl;

impl Foo for FooImpl { 
    fn foo(&self) {} 
}

fn do_foo(foo_doer: impl Foo) { 
    foo_doer.foo()
}
```

this line works:

```rust
do_foo(FooImpl {});
```

but when I try to run this:

```rust
do_foo(&FooImpl {});
```

I understandably get error: `the trait bound &FooImpl: Foo is not satisfied`.

I can obviously do this:

```rust
impl Foo for &FooImpl { fn foo(&self) {} }
```

and then it will work, but I'd have to do this for multiple types and I'd have to copy some code each time. Additionally in my case I can only get not only a borrow but a mutable borrow. Which means I have to impl it for `&mut FooImpl`, and sometimes I'd like to run it from an immutable borrow of the mutable borrow meaning I have to implement it for `&&mut FooImpl`, you get the idea.

My question is whether there is some trait impl / generic trickery you can recommend that will allow me to impl a trait for both owned instances and borrowed instances?

Alternatively can I change something on the `do_foo` function side that will allow it to accept both types of instances?

I have read [Do I have to implement a trait twice when implementing it for both reference and non-reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555910/do-i-have-to-implement-a-trait-twice-when-implementing-it-for-both-reference-and) and it works on my toy program. But my problem is the trait I am trying to impl in my actual code is from a different crate, so the compiler does will not allow me to impl `Borrow<FooImpl>` on that trait I think due to orphan rules (error: `type parameter B must be used as the type parameter for some local type`). Is there a solution that works around the orphan rules?

Comment: Define a macro and use that to generate your impls?

Comment: Applying Shepmaster's answer to the other question here: `impl<F: ?Sized> Foo for &'_ F where F: Foo {...}` will cover all your bases with regard to `&` references, and you can do the same for `&mut` references if you like. The `?Sized` bound is not strictly necessary, but lets you use the reference implementation for references to trait objects.

Comment: Also read [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/3650362) which explains why additional `impl`s are necessary.

Comment: @trentcl thank you, but my trait is in a different crate, forgot to mention it, see my edit. Also the second link was enlightening so thanks for that as well.

Comment: If it's in a different crate, either the crate itself should supply this `impl`, or there is something special about `FooImpl` that makes references to it special in that they can implement `Foo` although in general references to other types that implement `Foo` cannot. There is no general workaround (other than using a macro, as eggyal suggested) hat I know of, but there may be one for your specific case; unfortunately, the question does not contain enough information to suggest one.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether there is some trait impl / generic trickery you can recommend that will allow me to impl a trait for both owned instances and borrowed instances?

You might be able to [use Borrow/AsRef](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/implement-trait-for-value-and-reference/26102/9).

> sometimes I'd like to run it from an immutable borrow of the mutable borrow meaning I have to implement it for `&&mut FooImpl`, you get the idea.

Just reborrow to get either an `&FooImpl`?