# Is it possible to represent some trivially wrapped reference to a type as though it was wrapped owned value of that type?

Tags: rust, composition

I have a structure `Foo` which is composed of some other types and I implement a trait on some container of those various types ([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06932f45aeaa6c6618ff5a232a7d1ff8)):

```rust
struct MyType1 {}
struct MyType2 {}

struct Foo {
    field1: MyType1,
    field2: MyType2,
}

trait MyTrait {
    /// Just a simple default implementation to keep things simple
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("Hello world");
    }
}

struct MyContainer<T> {
    val: T,
}

// Use the default implementation for brevity.
impl MyTrait for MyContainer<Foo> {}
impl MyTrait for MyContainer<MyType1> {}
impl MyTrait for MyContainer<MyType2> {}
```

This should be fine.

Noting that `Foo` is really a composition of `MyType1` and `MyType2`, what I actually want to do is this, which doesn't work:

```rust
impl MyTrait for MyContainer<Foo> {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        // clearly this won't work as MyType1 and MyType2 are not `Copy`, nor
        // do I want to clone them.
        MyContainer {
            val: self.val.field1,
        }
        .do_something();
        MyContainer {
            val: self.val.field2,
        }
        .do_something();
    }
}
```

I can create a blanket implementation that covers the reference case:

```rust
impl<'a, T> MyTrait for MyContainer<&'a T>
where
    MyContainer<T>: MyTrait,
{
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("Inside ref trait")
    }
}
```

such that I can create a `MyContainer` around the reference:

```rust
impl MyTrait for MyContainer<Foo> {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        MyContainer {
            val: &self.val.field1,
        }
        .do_something();
        MyContainer {
            val: &self.val.field2,
        }
        .do_something();
    }
}
```

This doesn't address my problem because I want to run the implementation on `MyContainer<T>`, not `MyContainer<&T>`. `MyContainer` is a verification marker structure that denotes correct completion of a verification method on `T`. That is, putting a `T` in `MyContainer` denotes that `T` is somehow "verified". The composing structure implements the necessary verification trait. It's really part of the API in which it's not overly onerous to implement new `T`s, just a couple of traits is enough to have it work.

Since `MyContainer` is trivial, it seems to me that it ought to be possible to coerce this to create a transient representation of `MyContainer<T>` that does the right thing.

I'd prefer to do this with safe code, but unsafe might be the way to go. Is it possible to do what I want? Is there a better way to handle a wrapped composition structure?

This is different to other questions I've seen in which the trait is implemented on `T` and it is desired to implement it on `&T` without any extra effort. In this case, we have it implemented on `MyContainer<T>`, and I want it implemented on `MyContainer<&T>` *to act like it was a `MyContainer<T>`* without any extra effort on the part of the implementers of `MyType1` and `MyType2` and any future `MyTypeN`.

As per my understanding of the comments, I tried flipping the logic around, so that the implementation is made on the wrapped *reference* and the blanket implementation is imposed on the wrapped value, but I'm having trouble getting the trait bounds correct. The [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b209b4ebeb6805373d2934ba67310d15) shows the compiler recursing infinitely before it gives up.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Do I have to implement a trait twice when implementing it for both reference and non-reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56555910/155423); [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster edited to clarify difference with linked questions

Comment: And why is `MyContainer<&T>` invalid? It should indicate the same amount of verification.

Comment: It's not invalid, it just doesn't implement `do_something()`. I can impose on implementers that they must implement `MyTrait` for both `MyContainer<T>` and `MyContainer<&T>`, but it would be exactly the same code.

Comment: Why not provide blanket implementations that treat `T` and `&T` the same, as I linked? Then the implementor of `MyTrait` doesn't need to do anything special.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. The point is to provide the specific implementations for `MyContainer<&T>`, and then provide a blanket implementation to cover the `MyContainer<T: Borrow>` case. This seems embarrassingly obvious now I say it!

Comment: @Shepmaster I can't see what the trait bounds are to implement this for a wrapped struct. More info is added to the question. I'd really value your input!