# Implementing a trait for Option<T> and Option<&T>

Tags: rust

Suppose there is a trait, whose methods all only take a reference of `self`, such as

```
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32;
}
```

I'd like to have this trait implemented for both `Option<T>` and `Option<&T>` (as I can't always afford ownership), with a trivial implementation such as

```
impl<T: Trait> Trait for Option<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        if let Some(inner) = self { return inner.foo(); }
        0
    }
}

impl<T: Trait> Trait for Option<&T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        if let Some(inner) = self { return inner.foo(); }
        0
    }
}
```

However, doing so produces the following error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Trait` for type `std::option::Option<&_>`:
  --> option.rs:12:1
   |
5  | impl<T: Trait> Trait for Option<T> {
   | ---------------------------------- first implementation here
...
12 | impl<T: Trait> Trait for Option<&T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `std::option::Option<&_>`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `Trait` for type `&_`
```

Moreover, the implementations are literally the same. Is it possible to do this in a more compact way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a trait for reference and non reference types causes conflicting implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432842/implementing-a-trait-for-reference-and-non-reference-types-causes-conflicting-im)

Comment: It does not. I don't want to have one implementation for all reference types and another implementation for all non-reference types. I want to have the trait implemented for `Option<T>` where `T` is any type method `.foo()` could be applied on, i.e. where if `bar` is an instance of `T`, calling `bar.foo()` is valid.

Comment: As a workaround, you could implement your trait only for `Option<&T>` and document the fact that to use it with `Option<T>` user must first call `as_ref`. This is not the solution, strictly speaking, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but it might be useful.

Comment: I have considered that, but then I can't use `derive` macro on structs containing an `Option<T>` field to auto-derive the trait.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does not compile because I, as a user of your trait could do something like this:

```
struct Yo;

impl Trait for Yo {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 0 }
}
impl Trait for &Yo {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 { 1 }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Yo;
    let b: Option<&Yo> = Some(&a);
    b.foo(); // ambiguous call!
}
```

And there are two conflicting implementations of your trait for `Option<&Yo>`! Unfortunately trait specialization is still unstable, so that is probably not an option.

In your particular case you may solve with this generic `impl`, if you are willing:

```
impl<T: Trait> Trait for &T {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        (*self).foo()
    }
}
```

This, combined with your generic impl for `Option<T>`, will give an unambiguous implementation for `Option<&T>`.