# How to avoid needing `std::marker::Sized` when an associated type does not have a size?

Tags: rust

**Background**

I have a situation where I want to abstract over two different operation modes `Sparse` and `Dense`. Which one I pick is a compile time decision.

Orthogonal to these modes I have a number of `Kernels`. The implementation details and signatures of kernels differs between the two modes, but each mode has the same kernels. The kernel will be determined during runtime, based on a model file.

I now want to create a `BlackBox` that handles both modes and kernels.

**Simplified Code**

I removed additional kernels and the sparse mode.

```
pub struct XKernel;

pub trait KernelDense {
    fn compute_dense(&self, vectors: &[f32]);
}

impl KernelDense for XKernel {
    fn compute_dense(&self, vectors: &[f32]) {}
}

pub trait KernelCompute<V> {
    fn just_compute_it(&self, vectors: &[V]);
}

impl KernelCompute<f32> for (dyn KernelDense + 'static) {
    fn just_compute_it(&self, v: &[f32]) {
        self.compute_dense(v);
    }
}

pub trait Generalization {
    type V: 'static;

    type OperatorType: KernelCompute<Self::V>;

    fn set_kernel(&self, x: Box<Self::OperatorType>);

    fn compute(&self, v: &[Self::V]);
}

pub struct DenseVariant {
    x: Box<KernelDense>,
}

impl Generalization for DenseVariant {
    type V = f32;
    type OperatorType = KernelDense;

    fn set_kernel(&self, x: Box<KernelDense>) {}

    fn compute(&self, v: &[Self::V]) {
        self.x.compute_dense(v);
    }
}

struct BlackBox<'a, T>
where
    T: Generalization,
{
    computer: T,
    elements: &'a [T::V],
}

impl<'a, T> BlackBox<'a, T>
where
    T: Generalization,
{
    fn runtime_pick_operator_and_compute(&mut self) {
        self.computer.set_kernel(Box::new(XKernel));
        let s = self.elements.as_ref();
        self.computer.compute(s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // What I eventually want to do:
    // let black_box = BlackBox::<DenseVariant>::new();
    // black_box.runtime_pick_operator_and_compute();
}
```

[**Playground**](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=540507f664abd263b2c4dbb7ce24e64c&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

The code above produces the error

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn KernelDense + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:35:6
   |
35 | impl Generalization for DenseVariant {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn KernelDense + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-sized>
```

I tried adding copious amounts of `: Sized` (e.g., giving `BlackBox` a `where T: Generalization + Sized`, which eventually just produced different errors.

**Questions**

1. How can I implement `std::marker::Sized` for `(dyn KernelDense + 'static)` / make this program compile addressing the intention above?
2. Why does the compiler even care about `Generalization` being `Sized` (even when I add `T: Generalization + Sized` to `BlackBox`)? Isn't `BlackBox` (the only one using `Generalization`) being monomorphized into something that is `Generalization` (such as `DenseVariant`) which then clearly has a size of `Box`)?

Comment: You cannot "implement" `Sized`. Either something is or is not `Sized`, the compiler decides. A raw trait object will never be sized.

Comment: While the struct, which implements the trait, can be `Sized`, the Trait itself cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I can't really "implement" size and should have written "How can I ensure `Sized` is implemented for ...". Still, how can I make it compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is confusing. The `^^^`s are (misleadingly) pointing at `Generalization`, but the actual error says `dyn KernelDense`, which is `OperatorType`. Since at least Rust 1.50, you get a much better error message:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn KernelDense + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:42:9
   |
24 |         type OperatorType: KernelCompute<Self::V>;
   |         ------------------------------------------ required by this bound in `Generalization::OperatorType`
...
42 |         type OperatorType = KernelDense;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn KernelDense + 'static)`
```

Therefore, `OperatorType` is what really needs to be `Sized`. Associated types, [like generic type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044231/what-does-sized-is-not-implemented-mean), have an implicit `Sized` bound unless you specify otherwise by adding `?Sized` instead:

```
pub trait Generalization {
    ...
    type OperatorType: ?Sized + KernelCompute<Self::V>;
    ...
}
```

But you'll immediately run into another problem ([playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=900d57314fa3d4020883fc289a8a3d99&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:59:47
   |
59 |         self.computer.set_kernel(Box::new(XKernel));
   |                                           ^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct `XKernel`
   |
   = note: expected type `<T as Generalization>::OperatorType`
              found type `XKernel`
```

Which, if you read between the lines a little, is basically the compiler saying "What do I do with a `Box<XKernel>`? I need a `Box<T::OperatorType>` and I don't even know what `T` is yet!"

And that should make sense. Because there's no rule that forbids adding a new kind of variant where `OperatorType` is, let's say, `str`:

```
struct StringyVariant;

impl Generalization for StringyVariant {
    type V = f32;
    type OperatorType = str;
    
    fn set_kernel(&self, x: Box<str>) {}
    
    fn compute(&self, v: &[f32]) {}
}

impl KernelCompute<f32> for str {
    fn just_compute_it(&self, vectors: &[f32]) {}
}
```

No rules forbid these `impl`s, and yet it's impossible to coerce `Box<XKernel>` into `Box<str>`, so the blanket `impl` on `BlackBox` must be erroneous. It's missing a requirement: the requirement that `Box<XKernel>` can be coerced into `Box<T::OperatorType>`.

In stable Rust (as of 1.50) there is no way to write this requirement as a trait bound, so you must write two `impl`s (i.e., one for `BlackBox<DenseVariant>` and one for `BlackBox<SparseVariant>`), or perhaps find some other way around (like using `From` instead of coercion).

However, in nightly Rust, you can solve the original problem with a `CoerceUnsized` bound and an extra `as _` to hint to the compiler that it should coerce to something that makes sense:

```
// at top of file
#![feature(coerce_unsized)]

use std::ops::CoerceUnsized;

impl<'a, T> BlackBox<'a, T>
where
    T: Generalization,
    Box<XKernel>: CoerceUnsized<Box<T::OperatorType>>,
{
    fn runtime_pick_operator_and_compute(&mut self) {
        self.computer.set_kernel(Box::new(XKernel) as _);
        let s = self.elements.as_ref();
        self.computer.compute(s);
    }
}
```

[Here it is in the playground.](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=0111410ddd5763ae8e7f56f6dbb9a8fa&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last thing, you said "that actually needs to be Sized (*if you read carefully*) is OperatorType". Could you outline "how to read carefully" in this example, as it is totally not clear to me?

Comment: @left4bread That wasn't meant to be patronizing. I just meant you have to ignore where the carets are pointing and focus on the error message itself to figure out what the problem is. I can't find an issue for fixing this error message in the [Rust repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues), but you could file a new one.

Comment: No offense taken :) I just assumed there is a "standard recipe" for reading these kind of error messages that I missed. Again, thank you so much for your detailed explanation!