# Sized is not implemented error in data type with generic

Tags: rust

I'm experimenting with Rust and I cannot understand something about data types with generics.

Why does the following work:

```
trait IVertex {
}

struct GraphNode {
  datum: Box<IVertex>,
  edges: Vec<Rc<RefCell<GraphNode>>>,
}

struct Graph {
    nodes: HashMap<i32, Rc<RefCell<GraphNode>>>,
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
trait IVertex {
}

struct GraphNode<T: IVertex> {
    datum: Box<T>,
    edges: Vec<Rc<RefCell<GraphNode<T>>>>,
}

struct Graph {
    nodes: HashMap<i32, Rc<RefCell<GraphNode<IVertex>>>>,
}
```

The second one is raising the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn IVertex + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     nodes: HashMap<i32, Rc<RefCell<GraphNode<IVertex>>>>,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn IVertex + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
note: required by `GraphNode`
```

Of course the compiler can't know the size of the data type which is implementing `IVertex`. But if the values are wrapped in `Box` and `RefCell`, shouldn't it be ok? Because the pointer size is always the same?

The reason why I'm coming up with such a design is that I also have the following trait:

```
trait ISpecializedVertex : IVertex {
}
```

And I want to have another data structure, which is able to hold references to `GraphNode`, but only the ones containing `ISpecializedVertex`. Therefore I've added a generic in `GraphNode`.

Comment: You should read again the book about generics and traits. Generic structures get monomorphized, that means that `GraphNode<i32>` is a whole different type from `GraphNode<u32>`, for example.

Comment: Oh well! Now that makes sense, thanks. If there's some idiomatic rust pattern to achieve what I want then it would be nice to know, but I will also think about it on my own.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of [What does “Sized is not implemented” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/3650362) `dyn IVertex` is unsized, so to be able to have a `GraphNode<dyn IVertex>`, you have to add a `?Sized` bound to `T`.  See also [What does “dyn” mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/3650362)

Comment: @Świstak35 Did you make a typo? Did you intend to use a trait object or just want another generic argument [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=134b30c7f4d227557622559574244663)?