# Into<Iterator> vs Iterator for online algorithms

Tags: types, rust, iterator

I'm writing an online algorithm, implemented with a series of functions which take iterators and produce iterators.

When I write the function like thus (the content being more sophisticated but not different in terms of types):

```
fn decode<'a, T>(input: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i16> + 'a
where
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a u8> + 'a,
{
    input.map(|b| i16::from(*b)).filter(|i| *i != 0)
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=679400e17e22dc440b46eb0166b40569).

However, this makes calling the function unergonomic:

```
let input: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 0];
let v: Vec<i16> = decode(input.iter()).collect();
```

I'd prefer to use `T: Into<Iterator<...`, but I can't. When I write the signature thus:

```
fn decode<'a, T>(input: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i16> + 'a
where
    T: Into<Iterator<Item = &'a u8>> + 'a,
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e15b183f958fd1597d614939089f7bd3)

I get an error saying that the return type's size is not known at compile time:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item=&'a u8> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | / fn decode<'a, T>(input: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = i16> + 'a
2 | | where
3 | |     T: Into<Iterator<Item = &'a u8>> + 'a,
4 | | {
5 | |     input.into().map(|b| i16::from(*b)).filter(|i| *i != 0)
6 | | }
  | |_^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item=&'a u8> + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required by `std::convert::Into`
```

Why is this, and is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) instead:

```
fn decode<'a>(input: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a u8> + 'a) -> impl Iterator<Item = i16> + 'a {
    input.into_iter().map(|b| i16::from(*b)).filter(|i| *i != 0)
}
```

---

[`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) is a trait and traits do not have a size. This is why you cannot (yet) write:

```
fn example(x: Iterator<Item = ()>) {}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item=()> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | fn example(x: Iterator<Item = ()>) {}
  |            ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item=()> + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
  = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
```

[`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) is defined as:

```
pub trait Into<T> {
    fn into(self) -> T;
}
```

Something implementing `Into<dyn Iterator>` would have to have the function `fn into(self) -> dyn Iterator`, returning a trait. Since there's no size to a trait, it cannot (yet) be returned, stored in a variable, or accepted as an argument.

See also:

- [What does "Sized is not implemented" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28044231/155423)

Comment: I understand your example (why `fn a(x: Iterator<...>)` does not work), but I don't see the connection. Does my `.into()` call create an unsized type?

Anyway, `IntoIterator` does solve my problem; thanks!

Comment: @LeonoraTindall *Does my `.into()` call create an unsized type?* — yes.