# Rust dependency inject implementation of trait into another object

Tags: rust

In Rust, I am trying to create an object of type `Installer` and pass a `DownloaderFoo` or `DownloaderBar` to its constructor ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9fcb632a2d0f17faf0a2cbb886a30fd6)):

```rust
pub trait Downloader {
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct DownloaderFoo;
impl Downloader for DownloaderFoo {
    fn run(&self)  {
        println!("DownloaderFoo::run");
    }
}

pub struct DownloaderBar;
impl Downloader for DownloaderBar {
    fn run(&self)  {
        println!("DownloaderBar::run");
    }
}

pub struct Installer {
    downloader: Downloader,
}

impl Installer {
    pub fn run(&self) {
        self.downloader.run();
        println!("Installer::run");
    }
}

fn main() {
    Installer{downloader: DownloaderFoo{}}.run();
    Installer{downloader: DownloaderBar{}}.run();
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```sh
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
  --> src/main.rs:20:17
   |
20 |     downloader: Downloader,
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `dyn`: `dyn Downloader`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(bare_trait_objects)]` on by default

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:27
   |
30 |     Installer{downloader: DownloaderFoo{}}.run();
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Downloader`, found struct `DownloaderFoo`
   |
   = note: expected trait object `(dyn Downloader + 'static)`
                    found struct `DownloaderFoo`
```

I tried using `dyn Downloader` in the `Installer` members, but I'm a bit stuck and don't know how to move forward.

Any ideas here? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `dyn Downloader` does not have a size known at compile time. You can fix this by wrapping it in a `Box`, which is pointer to an object on the heap:

```rust
pub struct Installer {
    downloader: Box<dyn Downloader>,
}
```

And inject the Downloaders like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    Installer{downloader: Box::new(DownloaderFoo{})}.run();
    Installer{downloader: Box::new(DownloaderBar{})}.run();
}
```

For more information about the `Sized` trait, see [What does “Sized is not implemented” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044231/what-does-sized-is-not-implemented-mean)